# How to replace placeholder strings in document with contents from a file

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have two files, `A` and `B`.

File `A` is a letter, as below, which contains several placeholder strings on each line, like `<@userid>`.

```
<@U39RFF91U> for all the help in this project!

Thanks for your help to enhance the data quality <@U2UNRTLBV> <@U39RFF91U> <@U2UQCN023>!
Thanks for <@U38F4TBQ9> <@U38F5PQ73> <@U38F747CZ> <@U39RT0G07> and <@U2UQ17U20> ’s great work at the New Product!


Successful release! <@U2WHAAU9H> <@U2ML3C551> <@U38F4TBQ9> <@U38F747CZ> <@U39RT0G07> <@U2UQ17U20> <@U38F5PQ73> <@U2N64H7C6>!

Praise <@U2X0APW3Y> for going above and beyond to help with the retail campaign!
```

File `B` is a mapping table, mapping all user IDs to each user's name:

```
U39RFF91U  Person1
U2UNRTLBV  Person2
```

I'd like to work out a final file, `C`, with the content from the letter in `A`, but with all placeholders replaced by the corresponding content from the mapping table in file `B`.

Any idea how to do it via shell script on Linux?

Comment: Can you paste a sample output, how it is required

Comment: Is the required output. for checking defind person 1 as upkar. Also user name is not hardcoded it will refer from file B only  Upkar.  for all the help in this project!

Thanks for your help to enhance the data quality Karup Upkar <@U2UQCN023>!
Thanks for <@U38F4TBQ9> <@U38F5PQ73> <@U38F747CZ> <@U39RT0G07> and <@U2UQ17U20> .s great work at the New Product!


Successful release! <@U2WHAAU9H> <@U2ML3C551> <@U38F4TBQ9> <@U38F747CZ> <@U39RT0G07> <@U2UQ17U20> <@U38F5PQ73> <@U2N64H7C6>!

Praise <@U2X0APW3Y> for going above and beyond to help with the retail campaign!

Comment: Is it possible names map table to have spaces in user name and/or user id?

Answer (score 5):

You may transform the mappings into a `sed` editing script like this:

```
$ sed -r 's#^([^[:blank:]]*)[[:blank:]]+(.*)#s/<@\1>/\2/g#' user_map.txt >script.sed
```

Given the example, this will produce `script.sed` with the contents

```
s/<@U39RFF91U>/Person1/g
s/<@U2UNRTLBV>/Person2/g
```

You may then apply this editing script to the text file:

```
$ sed -f script.sed letter.txt >completed_letter.txt
```

Comment: This is a case where awk is more trouble than it's worth.  Just handle the first space delimiter explicitly, using sed, and [you don't have to worry about spaces in the person names.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340290/135943)

Comment: @Wildcard I was lazy and added support for multi-word names as an afterthought. Fixed it now. Thanks for the poke.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done either with sed or even using just bash tools .

Classic bash solution:

```
var="$(cat file.txt)";while read -r id name;do var="${var//@$id/$name}";done<mapfile.txt;echo "$var"
```

You can append `>newfile.txt` to the last command to send the final text in a newfile.

Sed solution with writting changes to the same file:

```
while read -r id name;do sed -i "s/\@$id/$name/g" textfile.txt;done<mapfile.txt
```

This solution may perform slower if mapfile / text file are quite large, since external app sed is called for every entry found stored in map file.

Both solutions work ok with your sample.

```
$ cat b.txt
<@U39RFF91U> for all the help in this project!
Thanks for your help to enhance the data quality <@U2UNRTLBV> <@U39RFF91U> <@U2UQCN023>!

$ cat c.txt
U39RFF91U  Person1
U2UNRTLBV  Person2

$ var="$(cat b.txt)";while read -r id name;do var="${var//@$id/$name}";done<c.txt #Batch Solution
$ echo "$var" 
<Person1> for all the help in this project!
Thanks for your help to enhance the data quality <Person2> <Person1> <@U2UQCN023>!

$ while read -r id name;do sed -i "s/\@$id/$name/g" b.txt;done<c.txt #SED solution
$ cat b.txt
<Person1> for all the help in this project!
Thanks for your help to enhance the data quality <Person2> <Person1> <@U2UQCN023>!
```

Answer (score 1):

File B:

```
U39RFF91U  Person1
U2UNRTLBV  Person2
```

File A as noted, with e.g. `<@U39RFF91U>` in the text.

---

Simple working code (one-liner):

```
sed -e "$(sed -E 's_^([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+(.*)$_s/<@\1>/\2/g_' file_B)" file_A
```

---

Essentially equivalently:

```
sed -e "$(sed 's_  *_>/_;s_^_s/<@_;s_$_/g_' file_B)" file_A
```

<sub>(Only difference is no handling of tab characters.)</sub>

---

You might want to proofread the result.  It looks like you will very probably be missing some commas for it to be good English.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's#(\S+)\s+(.*)#s/<@\1>/\2/g#' map | sed -f- data
```

Comment: I have updated my answer.