# Bash perform variable expansion of string

Tags: bash

I'm trying to have two layers of indirection, though let me know if I'm a victim of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

#### Boiled Down Explanation of What I'd Like to Achieve

```
> test1=\$test2
> test2="string to print"
> echo $test2
string to print
> echo $test1
$test2
```

This all makes sense, but what I *want* is to perform a command using `$test1` and print out `string to print`.  My gut reaction was that this should work

```
> echo $(echo $test1)
$test2
```

Bollocks.  Does anyone else know if this is possible?

#### More Detailed Explanation of Why I Wish to Accomplish This

I want to create a text file template containing `$variables` which can be re-used to generate many text files.  My thinking is: set environment variables, process the template file and output to another file.

Example:

```
> #set vars
> cat template.txt | magic_var_expansion_cmd > out1.txt
> #set vars
> cat template.txt | magic_var_expansion_cmd > out2.txt
> #set vars
> cat template.txt | magic_var_expansion_cmd > out3.txt
```

This could obviously be used in a script, and in more sophisticated ways but this is the [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product) in my mind's eye.

Comment: You can use parameter expansion for this: `echo ${test1@P}`. See this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731950/133046

Answer (score 16):

```
$ test1="hello"
$ test2="test1"

$ echo "${!test2}"
hello
```

From the `bash` manual:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (`!`), and
>          parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of variable
>          indirection.  Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest
>          of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then
>          expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather
>          than the value of parameter itself.  This is known as indirect
>          expansion.  If parameter is a nameref, this expands to the name of the
>          variable referenced by parameter instead of performing the complete
>          indirect expansion.  The exceptions to this are the expansions of
>          `${!prefix*}` and `${!name[@]}` described below.  The exclamation point
>          must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce
>          indirection.

For the second part of the question, I would probably try to avoid using actual shell variables in the template, and instead use easy to parse placeholders and replace these using a tool like `sed`.

There are a few similar questions around, including "[How to replace placeholder strings in document with contents from a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340246/how-to-replace-placeholder-strings-in-document-with-contents-from-a-file)", "[Tool to create text files from a template](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59620/tool-to-create-text-files-from-a-template)" and "[How to replace a list of placeholders in a text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19970/how-to-replace-a-list-of-placeholders-in-a-text-file)" (and there are others too).

Comment: This is really close to what I was looking for, with one wrinkle.  If it were `test2=test1 hello`, then echo `"${!test2}"` doesn't print `"hello hello"`, it prints nothing.

Comment: If the string contains variables, but isn't exculsively itself the name of a variable, is this possible?

Comment: what about something more complicated? `#export RUN_CMD=$(echo $('$HOME/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_diversity_with_task2vec.py --manual_loads_name diversity_ala_task2vec_delauny > $OUT_FILE 2> $ERR_FILE'))`

Comment: @CharlieParker I don't really see how this is related. If you want to run a command in a variable, you should most likely make that variable an array: `runcmd=( "$HOME"/somepath/script.py --options here ); "${runcmd[@]}" >out 2>err`.

Comment: @Kusalananda it's complicated to explain, but I just need to create the string I need (but happy to explain).

Comment: @CharlieParker You would best do that in a brand new question.  That way other people may get a chance to give better answers than I could ever give in a comment.

Comment: @Kusalananda here it is: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/726079/how-does-one-store-the-evaluation-of-a-big-string-with-multiple-env-variables-v

Answer (score 9):

use [eval](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/eval.1p.html)

```
$ test1=\$test2
$ test2="string to print"
$ echo $test2
string to print
$ eval echo $test1
string to print
```

Comment: This is also useful for "deliteralizing" strings with special characters like tildes or curly braces so they can be passed around in a variable for later expansion.

Comment: how do I store it in a variable? e.g. `export RUN_CMD=(eval echo '$HOME/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_diversity_with_task2vec.py --manual_loads_name diversity_ala_task2vec_delauny > $OUT_FILE 2> $ERR_FILE')`